# How do I log in to chat?

Tags: support, chat

Even though I'm logged in here (buddhism.SE), I don't appear to be logged into our chat area. Any ideas why? I'm wondering if it's because we're still in beta and so buddhism.SE is still not considered a full-blown StackExchange site?

Answer (score 1):

There's a link at the top under StackExchange:

[image: link to chat]

Here's the actual link to the main chat room:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism

Edit: you also need to be logged in as your Buddhism user:

[image: link to chat login]

Get to this page by clicking on your user name at the top on chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, I've been there and can see the discussions. But at the bottom it says "You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information.", and I don't see anywhere that I can join the chat.

Comment: Also, a weirdness that may be related. When I committed for beta, I did it under a specific email address. Then when beta started I was notified on that email address, but when I tried to login it said it had never heard of me. So I explicitly registered with the same email address. Then as recently as this morning I got an email poking me to contribute, even though I already have been. I wonder if the site thinks there's two of me?

Comment: Are you logged into chat as your Buddhism user?

Comment: Well I'm logged into SE as my Buddhism user, and then I click the link to go to chat and I'm taken to the same place your link took me to. At the moment there are three chat boxes, and I click on the first. I am taken to a long screen of chats, but at the bottom it says "You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information." The "logged in" is a link, so I click on that and I see "Please log in to any StackExchange site first, or log in via StackExchange.com." But I'm *already* logged into a StackExchange site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm bumping into an account collision between my current account and a years old one I no longer use. I probably need to escalate this to the SE gods. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Did you see my edit? You need to be logged in as the right user.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I have an old account called "tkp" which is connected both to buddhism.SE and to area51.SE. It and my current "Tommy" account are both registered to the same email address. I can only login to buddhism.SE with my main account, but I can only login to chat with tkp. I've contacted SE to have it fixed.

Comment: Responding to Tommy directly through the contact system, but for the record, users don't need to have Buddhism as their parent user on their chat profile to chat with us. As long as their parent profile has sufficient reputation, they'll be able to get in.